# Failed to grant permission in DolphinDB

Tags: dolphindb, operation

I create a user and grant him read permission for all databases and tables. However, when I log in as this user, related permission is not granted as expected. The following is my script:

```
grant('superUsers', DB_READ, '*')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DolphinDB, a single character wrapped with single quotes is recognized as a CHAR, instead of a STRING. You should use double quotes for the third parameter “*”, as shown in the following script:

```
grant('superUsers', DB_READ, "*")
```